# Iterated modulus of the form $n-(n \bmod k)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have a recursion formula $f_{n,k}(0)=n$ and $f_{n,k}(i)=n-f_{n,k}(i-1)\bmod k$ where $n,k$ are positive integers and $k<n$.
I can write for example $f_{n,k}(2) = n-(n- n\bmod k)\bmod k $ but I am wondering whether I can write this in a compact form. Playing around with wolframalpha did not really bring me any insights and using small examples like $n=5$ and $k=2$ gave me the impression that there is a periodic behaviour, e.g., $f_{5,2}(2)=5=f_{5,2}(0)$, or $f_{7,3}(2)=7=f_{7,3}(0)$.

Is there anything general that can be said? And can the $\mathrm{mod}$ structure be reduced?

Comment: Modulo $k$ you are just oscilating between two values $n$ and $0$, so except first value (where you do not apply $\bmod$), it will be just $n \bmod k$ ($i$ even) or $n-n \bmod k$ ($i$ odd).

Comment: You can show the above also by proving that $(n- n\bmod k)\bmod k=0$